# SSIS Package how to import CSV lines selectively based on query

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, ssis

I have multiple CSV files with a 100 or so columns each that I want to import into an SQL database using an SSIS package. These CSV files are received every night, and I want our SQL tables to function as a history/track changes table.

In other words I'm required to evaluate each line of the CSV prior to import based on a unique identifier. I need to check the latest (based on date of import) entry of an ID in the table, and if it exists & differs from the new line in the CSV, it should be imported. If it's a duplicate, it should be ignored. if it doesn't exist at all, it should also be imported.

I can't simply filter out all duplicates, as a change from X to Y and then back to X should be recorded in the table (as it's a history/change table).

Originally I tried to get this working with a flat file import -> Lookup tool -> DB destination, but it doesn't look as though I can modify the lookup tool to use a specific query as opposed to just comparing the indicated columns with a DB to see if it exists. Is there a way to achieve this using the provided SSIS tools? The only alternative that I can see is creating a custom script task to evaluate each line in the CSV beforehand and writing it to a temp table or a new CSV with only the data that needs to be inserted. This might be a perfectly viable solution but I'm afraid of performance issues.

Comment: Personally, for processes like this, I prefer to perform a "ELT" process instead; Extract, Load, Transform. Extract and :oad the whole file into a staging table on your SQL Server, and then perform the matching on your production table; perhaps by use of a `MERGE`.